# scattered from, against, or by?

Tags: adverbs

A quick Google search gives me the following sentences:

1. An electron is scattered from a nucleus.
2. An electron is scattered against a nucleus.
3. An electron is scattered by a nucleus.

Which one is correct? If they are all correct, then what is the difference in the meaning?

Comment: google 'electron scatter nucleus'. Answer: 'from' or 'off'.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to say. I'm no particle physicist, but I do try to keep up with the basics. None of these sentences seem to match anything I know about how electrons interact with nuclei. Are we talking about the nucleus the electron was originally associated with?

Comment: Thinking about it, if we're talking about what happens in an [scanning electron microscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_diffraction), for example, you could say the ***beam** of electrons* is "scattered **by** the nuclei". But any single electron isn't "scattered" - it's **deflected** (or **diffracted**, I suppose, depending on whether it's considered as a particle or a wave).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right that a single electron is deflected which is just 'singular' for scattered. Since in Physics we talk about **electron scattering** it is fine (and common) in that context to also say that just one electron is scattered.

Comment: @alexlo: Well, if we were talking about "normal" English usage, I'd have to assume the "scattered" electron was broken into many parts (quarks?) that went off in different directions. But I see from Google Books that you guys use the word that way: [the electron is **scattered**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+electron+is+scattered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 13300 hits in Google Books. The same string with **deflected/diffracted** gets 5180/181. If I insert **beam** then *scattered/deflected/diffracted* get 2310/18900/653. Weird.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was talking about an incident electron, not one of the electrons associated with the nucleus. An electron is a fundamental particle. It cannot be separated further. I was asking an English question. If the context distracts people, please allow me to modify the question to be "A ball is scattered ? another ball".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you that we are talking physics jargon here. As Jing pointed out, there is no **physical** ambiguity here, due to the specific nature of electrons. As far as I can remember from my physics courses though, one would also speak about atoms being scattered and similarly reduce this to an atom being scattered. This is physically slightly different as an atom can be broken apart. I guess a reason may be found in the description of what a *classical scattering experiment* looks like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom_scattering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the sentences are practically correct (except the 1st has to be slightly changed to derive meaning from it), but have different meanings.

> 1. *An electron is scattered from a nucleus.* should be *An electron is scattered **away** from a nucleus.* and would mean that an electron was on its way to hitting the nucleus, but was scattered in a different direction by something in its path before arrival.
> 2. Similarly, *An electron is scattered against a nucleus.* would mean that it was 'flying' in space and hit some object by which it was scattered in the direction of the nucleus and hit it.
> 3. *An electron is scattered by a nucleus.* means that the electron hit the nucleus which resulted in a change of direction of the electron.

Note that only the 3rd option describes/clarifies the **cause** of the electron being scattered (namely the nucleus), while the other two refer to the **effect** of the scattering (the electron hitting or not hitting the nucleus).

Comment: thank you very much. It is a very clear answer. I accept it. By the way, can I say "An electron is scattered with a nucleus"?

Comment: You could say that as well. Then it would mean that **with the help of a nucleus** you, or someone else, scattered the electron.

Comment: Alexo. Good answer, indeed. However, the question is essentially about preposition use. OP ought to have done some homework on the difference between the prepositions in the example sentence. If still not sure, he could ask on ELL. On ELU this would be GR.